# could not find method compile() for arguments [org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13]

Tags: java, gradle, httpclient

When I run the project using intellij, it works fine, but when I run it through cmd, it says:

"Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'

}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal).

Comment: thank you so much. Spent hours to fix this but it was in fact just one word to change... You saved my life!